# my on-prem hadoop-cluster is slowly access aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop

I have a on-prem hadoop-cluster
I made this cluster connect aws s3, using s3a schema
but cluster access s3, very slowly

I suspect the s3a-file-system metrics system is the cause.
or authenticating with Amazon is taking a long time.

which one is made this cluster slowly

this is my command line

```
[flamingo@ex-nn01 hadoop]$ hdfs dfs -ls s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db
2023-07-19 16:28:01,190 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2023-07-19 16:28:01,256 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 999 second(s).
2023-07-19 16:28:01,256 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system started
Found 6 items
drwxrwxrwx   - flamingo flamingo          0 2023-07-19 16:28 s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/airlines
drwxrwxrwx   - flamingo flamingo          0 2023-07-19 16:28 s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/airports
drwxrwxrwx   - flamingo flamingo          0 2023-07-19 16:28 s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/carriers
drwxrwxrwx   - flamingo flamingo          0 2023-07-19 16:28 s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/dummytext_1mb
drwxrwxrwx   - flamingo flamingo          0 2023-07-19 16:28 s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/planes
drwxrwxrwx   - flamingo flamingo          0 2023-07-19 16:28 s3a://ebigs-s3/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/test1
2023-07-19 16:28:12,669 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping s3a-file-system metrics system...
2023-07-19 16:28:12,669 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system stopped.
2023-07-19 16:28:12,669 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: s3a-file-system metrics system shutdown complete.
```

1. how to disable s3a-file-system metrics system
2. or made fast access s3